# Is $\frac{|x|^2 - 2x_1^2}{|x|^4}$ integrable near the origin?

Tags: calculus, integration

Here $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and the integration can be taken over the ball $B(0,1)$, for example. Bounding from above, we get
$$
\int_{B(0,1)} \left| \frac{|x|^2 - 2x_1^2}{|x|^4} \right| \thinspace dx \leq \int_{B(0,1)} \frac{3}{|x|^2} \thinspace dx = \infty
$$
Does there exist a tighter bound that would show that the integral is finite? Or does there exist a lower bound which would show that the integral is infinite?

Comment: It is $\infty$ and you get it easily by going to polar coordinates.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.